# Ordinal Logistic Modeling

Tags: logistic, ordered-logit

When making ordinal logistic models and you have two or more parameters how can you tell which one has a greater effect on the response variable?

Answer (score 5):

The word "greater" here is poorly defined. The coefficient will tell you the effect of a unit change in the explanatory variable on the linear predictor, $x'\beta$ part of your model. However, if $X_1$ takes values 0 and 1, and $X_2$ varies from -10 to +200, a unit change in the first one is A LOT, and a unit change in the other is minuscule compared to the range of data.

The type of analysis that attempts to make these comparisons more meaningful is known (in econometrics) as analysis of marginal effects. Stata computes them with `margins` commands (`mfx` in older versions), which would produce the differences in category probabilities after `ologit` (and you can tweak it to produce pretty much anything).

A poor man's version of this analysis would be to rescale your variables: either to have unit variance, or to range from 0 to 1. Then their estimated coefficients would be more like apples to apples.